# Function with 1/2 values and short variable declaration assigned twice to same variable

Tags: go

I have two questions for following code

1. `emptyinterface.(int)` can return one or two values, how the function is defined to achieve that effect?
2. `ok` has been declared twice using short variable declaration, why it is possible in this context?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var emptyinterface interface{}
    emptyinterface=4

    i1:=emptyinterface.(int)
    fmt.Println(i1)
    i2,ok:=emptyinterface.(int)//<- how the function is defined such that it can return either 1 (i1) or 2 values (i2,ok)?
    fmt.Println(i2,ok)
    i3,ok:=emptyinterface.(string) //<--why I can reassign to ok, which has assign previously?
    fmt.Println(i3,ok)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not a function, it's a language feature. You can't write a function that does that, but the compiler writers can create a bit of syntax that does.
2. A `:=` is invalid if there are *no* new variables on its left side. If there is at least one new variable being declared, it's allowed.

Answer (score 2):

In each of the cases, there is at-least new variable created along with `ok`, i.e. `i2` and `i3`, so redeclaration of `ok` is perfectly fine.

This is well documented in the language spec (emphasis mine) under [Short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may **redeclare** variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least **one of the non-blank variables is new**. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration.

Also it is unclear, what you are referring as a function here, [Type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) is a feature of the language that asserts if a value within the interface is of a particular type. It always returns the underlying value if the assertion was successful or a failure if its not. You should always be checking the return value of the type assertion (2nd argument) before meaningfully using it elsewhere.